# Problem implementing a generic method in a generic type which inherits from a non-generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a non-generic interface with two generic method signatures.

```
interface IDataContainer
{
    T GetValue<T>();
    void SetValue<T>(T value);
}
```

Then I have a generic class that implements IDataContainer

```
public class DataContainer<T>: IDataContainer
{
    private T _value;

    #region IDataContainer Members

    public T GetValue<T>()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public void SetValue<T>(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I am getting an error about not being able to implicitly convert type T to T on the GetValue and SetValue methods that were implemented.

Is there a way to solve this?  Some sort of type constraint for equality?  Is there a better way?

I know that I could just make IDataContainer generic by making it `IDataContainer<T>`, but then I could not have a List of IDataContainers when T is not always the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the compiler sees two different types. T in the scope of IDataContainer is not the same T as in the scope of your generic method, and thus the compiler complains.

Because your container holds an instance of T, I think your interface should also have the type-parameter T (not just a method-scope generic parameter).

Your current interface actually promises (remember, an interface is a contract), to be able to deliver a value of T for any T - surely that is not what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

The intent of your code would be nicely captured in a generic interface:

```
interface IDataContainer<T> {
  T GetValue();
  void SetValue(T value);
}
```

So why do you have a non-generic interface with generic methods?

The problem with the generic methods is that the type parameter *is not the same*, although they have the same name.

To have a list of data containers for when T is not the same, just have a non-generic base interface for your generic interface:

```
interface IDataContainer { }

interface IDataContainer<T> : IDataContainer { 
  ...
}
```

Then you can have a list of the non-generic data container.

Comment: But then I could not have a List of IDataContainers when T is not always the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Those two methods mean two different things. In IDataContainer, you specify a generic method. This can be called with any type. In `DataContainer`, you specify methods which take the specific type parameter specified in the class. `IDataContainer`'s contract is not satisfied by `DataContainer`. You should change `IDataContainer` so that it's generic.

To make it more clear, consider `IDataContainer` in isolation. The following code should be legal regardless of the concrete container returned by `getContainer()`

```
IDataContainer ctr = getContainer();
String x = ctr.getValue<String>();
```

However, if getContainer looked like the following, then that code would clearly break if what you had was legal:

```
public IDataContainer getContainer() {
    return new DataContainer<Foo>();
}
```

The fundamental problem you have is that if you have DataContainers for different types, then the contracts for those DataContainers are just fundamentally different. A `DataContainer<Foo>` has a `GetValue` that gives you a `Foo`, while a `DataContainer<Bar>` has a `GetValue` that gives you a `Bar`. If there's a superclass of both Foo and Bar, then you can use that, otherwise, you're going to be casting, because you simply can't guarantee type-safety if you toss them both into a list together.